# How to update sql table join on 3 columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to **update my table Products but only for the rows that are in my temporary table**, see below:

```
Table Products

PkProduct   Price   DateChanged 
1           4.99    2013-01-01  
1           5.99    2014-01-01  
2           10.50   2000-01-01  
2           12.50   2002-01-01  
2           14.50   2003-01-01  
3           0.99    2000-01-01  
4           0.99    2000-01-01  
5           0.99    2000-01-01  

Temporary Table #temptable

PkProduct   Price   DateChanged
2           12.50   2002-01-01
2           14.50   2003-01-01
```

You can see that my #temptable contain row **equal** to the table Products
I want to set a new price for both those rows let say `@variableNewPrice = 2.75`

I'm trying to create a join in my update code:

```
UPDATE Products
SET Price = @variableNewPrice
FROM Products p1
RIGHT JOIN #temptable p2
ON p2.PkProduct = p1.PkProduct 
AND p2.Price = p1.Price
AND P2.DateChanged = p1.DateChanged
```

It's not working really well. I tried with only the `PkProduct = PkProduct` but then every row for this PkProduct where changed! I don't have a column PkProduct that is a real unique Pk for the table.

I appreciate your help =)

Comment: You have a typo on your last `ON` clause.  Should be: `AND P1.DateChanged = p2.DateChanged`

Comment: Also, why are you using `RIGHT JOIN`?  It sounds like you should be using an `INNER JOIN` for this.

Comment: Do you really want to update rows? Shouldn't a price change create new rows?

Comment: @Siyual I corrected the typo, in my code it was correct.
I tried the` INNER JOIN` but it was not working either
@jalynn2 I usually insert row, but when someone inserted a lots of row and made a mistake, we don't want to add a new row for all the product, but find a way to edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
UPDATE  P
SET     Price = @variableNewPrice
FROM    Products    P
JOIN    #temptable  T   ON  P.PkProduct = T.PkProduct 
                        AND P.Price = T.Price
                        AND P.DateChanged = T.DateChanged
```

There were two issues with the query - the last `ON` clause was `T.DateChanged = T.DateChanged` which would always be true.  The other issue is that you were also doing an `OUTER JOIN` which doesn't make sense in this context.  I modified the query to use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I tried your modification (p.Datechanged were correct in my SQL), and the `INNER JOIN`, but nothing is happening.. Can it be my type of column? In Product Price is `Real`and in my `temptable` it's a `FLOAT`

Comment: Hey! That was it! the `INNER JOIN`with the change of type (I changed the one of my #temptable to `REAL`) Thanks you really much :D